# IIS version control with Mac clients

Tags: version-control

We are in a unique situation here at work.  Most of our websites are on an IIS server, but our developers are on Macs.  We need some kind of way to do version control of our websites, but want to manage them locally on our Macs.  Is there any way to do this, short of Powershell?  Most of our websites are in PHP, so we don't want a solution that is geared toward ASP.NET.  Also, I'm not clear if there is a way to use Subversion with IIS.  Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Source control and code execution can be considered as orthogonal. [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
might be a solution for your requirements, as it does not enforce a central repository.

IIS has no implications on version control, as long as you choose a version control system that has a client on the Microsoft platform. Concerning subversion there are plenty clients for Microsoft derivates.